# PHP get the strings separate to store in the array

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on my PHP to fetch the data from the mysql database. I have got a problem with storing the filename in the array using the values when I have stored both filenames in a database.

Here is what I have stored in the blob:

```
draft_attachment.rar
draft_attachment - Copy.rar
```

Here is the code:

```
$mailbox = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM draft WHERE id = ?");
$mailbox->execute([$id]);

// set the resulting array to associative
$row = $mailbox->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$attachments = array();

if($mailbox->rowCount() == 1)
{
    $attachment = array();
    $draft_to = htmlspecialchars($row['to_email']);
    $draft_subject = quoted_printable_decode($row['subject']);
    $draft_message = $row['message'];
    $attach[] = $row['attachments'];
}
?>
```

When I try this:

```
$attach[] = $row['attachments'];
```

It will store both strings in the array:

```
Array
{
   [0] => draft_attachment.rar
draft_attachment - Copy.rar
}
```

So I have tried this:

```
$attachments = array();  
$i = 0;

if($mailbox->rowCount() == 1) {
    $attachments[$i] = $row['attachments'];
    $i++;
}
```

It wont store the strings separate so I dont know what to do.

Here is what I want to achieve:

```
Array
{
   [0] => draft_attachment.rar
   [1] => draft_attachment - Copy.rar
}
```

Can you please show me an example how I could get both strings to go separate so I could be able to store them in the array using the value?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually storing any binary data in that blob? If not, you need a better approach. If you were to use a lookup table (varchar) that would provide the one => many relationships you appear to need. Then no need to separate any strings.

Comment: `"`'s are valid chars in an email address, htmlspecialchars is going to bork it, XSS is not a thing with to address, instead you should be preventing header injection, which htmlspecialchars wont prevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string using [`preg_split`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) on `\R` (any sequence of new line characters) (`explode` can also work if you know the exact line ending characters):

```
$attachments = preg_split('/\R/', $row['attachments']);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/3g54m)

Comment: Thank you very much for this as this is what I am looking for exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use explode function, something like `explode("\n", $row['attachments'])`